# Problems calling function after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I'm having problems getting this to work. I'm using jQuery to call for the resizeWindow function to be run any time the browser window is resized. The resizeWindow function does work as intended, however, adjusting the browser window size doesn't seem to be invoking the function to run again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Bind the window onresize event
    $(window).bind('resize', resizeWindow);

    //Call resizeWindow() function immediately to intially set elements
    $(window).bind('load', resizeWindow);
});

function resizeWindow(){
    //Find all the container parent objects
    $('.container').each(function(){
            //Initialize the height variable
            var maxHeight = 0;

            //Cache the jQuery object for faster DOM access and performance
            var $borders = $(this).find('.border');

            //Find all the border child elements within this specific container
            $borders.each(function(){
                    //Get current element's height
                    var thisHeight = $(this).height();

                    //Check if the current height is greater than the max height thus far
                    //If so, change max height to this height
                    if (thisHeight>maxHeight) maxHeight = thisHeight;
            });

            //Now that we have the maximum height of the elements,
            //set that height for all the .border child elements inside the parent element
            $borders.height(maxHeight);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you build a fiddle demonstrating your problem ? There doesn't seem to be problems in your binding.

Comment: I have no problems getting this to work as expected. Fiddle would be lovely.

Comment: The function is called in your page. Put a breakpoint to see it.

Comment: Do you mean the boxes "step by step" and below? They're getting the same height as the upper ones, as your code instructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you manually setting the height of the borders when the function is first called it stopping the sizes from adjusting when the window is resized.

Try adding this line right after `var $borders`:

```
$borders.css({height:'auto'});
```